# Vue component memory leaks can cause its parent components to leak

Tags: vue.js, memory-leaks, components, parent, children

i'm using Vue2, I found that vue component memory leaks can cause its parent components to leak. Is this caused by the use of $parent and $children links between parent and child components?

Why not Vue break this link when destroying components to minimize the impact of leaks?

my demo:

for son components, which EventBus is not off, causing the son component to memory leak

```
<template>
  <div>son</div>
</template>

<script>
import EventBus  from '../EventBus'
export default {
    mounted() {
        EventBus.on('page1son1', this.testFun)
    }
}
</script>
```

for parent components, which has no risk of memory leaks

```
<template>
   <div>parent<son></son></div>
</template>
    
<script>
  import son from './son'
  export default {

  }
```

I found in devtools that when the son components leaks，the parent components leaks，so i go to see the vue source code.As follows.

```
Vue.prototype.$destroy = function () {
 const vm: Component = this
 if (vm._isBeingDestroyed) {
   return
 }
 callHook(vm, 'beforeDestroy')
 vm._isBeingDestroyed = true
 // remove self from parent
 const parent = vm.$parent
 if (parent && !parent._isBeingDestroyed && !vm.$options.abstract) {
   remove(parent.$children, vm)
 }
 // teardown scope. this includes both the render watcher and other
 // watchers created
 vm._scope.stop()
 // remove reference from data ob
 // frozen object may not have observer.
 if (vm._data.__ob__) {
   vm._data.__ob__.vmCount--
 }
 // call the last hook...
 vm._isDestroyed = true
 // invoke destroy hooks on current rendered tree
 vm.__patch__(vm._vnode, null)
 // fire destroyed hook
 callHook(vm, 'destroyed')
 // turn off all instance listeners.
 vm.$off()
 // remove __vue__ reference
 if (vm.$el) {
   vm.$el.__vue__ = null
 }
 // release circular reference (#6759)
 if (vm.$vnode) {
   vm.$vnode.parent = null
 }
```

In the source code of Vue, I didn't find a place to break the reference of $parent, so I guess it is because the $parent of the child component refers to the parent component, so the memory leak of the child component will cause the leak of the parent component

Comment: The use of $parent and $children is a bad practice that should be avoided under normal circumstances, this is one of reasons.  It's impractical or impossible for the framework to do this for you, but it's unknown why this happens in your case. The question is not constructive without specific examples of code.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I can understand that EventBus causes the memory leak of son components, but why the parent components also leaks, it only contains son components.

Comment: I see what you mean. It would make no sense to explicitly detach a child from a parent because child leak is already extremely bad, this would only make it harder to determine the origin of orphan child if there were no $parent when a leak is debugged

Comment: What you said does make sense. But I don't think it is completely meaningless to cut off the links and ensure the smallest leak impact. My scene is that I want to locate which component has a memory leak by finding components that have been destroyed but not garbage collected. However, due to the links between parent and child components, a large number of components have not been garbage collected, so I cannot pinpoint the source of the leak.

Comment: Makes sense either. I'd suggest to post an issue in Vue repo and bring this argument, could possibly lead somewhere

Comment: Ok, I raised an issue here https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/12959, hope to get a reply